# Gaussian is the only radial function which is separable

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

One way to characterize the Gaussian $ae^{b x^2}$ is that its a $C^1$ function $h$ that is *radial* $h(x,y) = h(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ and also *separable*, that is expressible as a product of one-dimensional functions $h(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$.

How can I show this?

I can write $h(x,y) = f(x)f(y) = f(r)f(0)$.  If $h \in C^2$ then I can use the Laplacian to $\Delta h = \partial^2_r h + \frac 1 r \partial_r h$ to get $f''(x)f(y) + f(x)f''(y) =  f(0) f''(r) + \frac 1 r f(0)f'(r)$.  At the point $y=0$ this becomes $f(0)f'(x) = x f(x) f''(0)$, an ODE whose solution is exactly what I want.

But is there a simpler argument which uses only the first derivative, or perhaps an integral?  My textbook suggests the  $C^2$ assumption isn't needed here

Comment: Is it not enough to say (for potentially elliptical radius) $$e^{r^2}=e^{ax^2+by^2}=e^{ax^2}e^{by^2}$$

Comment: @grdgfgr I want to go the other way-- if $h(x,y) = f(x)f(y)$ and $h(x,y)=h(x',y')$ when $x^2+y^2 = x'^2+y'^2$ then $h(x,y) = ae^{b(x^2+y^2)}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's just take $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $h: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Since $h$ is separable,
$$
h(\mathbf{x}) = \prod_jf(x_j) \tag{1}
$$
and since $h$ is radially symmetric,
$$
h(\mathbf{x}) = g(||\mathbf{x}||^2) \tag{2}
$$
for some $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, and $g: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$.

Observe the partial derivative using $(1)$:
$$
h_{x_j} = \frac{f'(x_j)}{f(x_j)}h(\mathbf{x})
$$
and using $(2)$:
$$
h_{x_j} = g'(||\mathbf{x}||^2)2x_j
$$

Now equate the two:
$$
\frac{f'(x_j)}{f(x_j)}h(\mathbf{x}) = g'(||\mathbf{x}||^2)2x_j
$$
or...
$$
\frac{f'(x_j)}{2x_jf(x_j)} = \frac{g'(||\mathbf{x}||^2)}{g(||\mathbf{x}||^2)}
$$
Since this must hold for all $j$, the above must equal to a constant. This yields the result.